Is it legal to give prospective employees an IQ test?
Is it legal to give prospective employees an IQ test?
Suppose that the job requires one to be intelligent and/or a quick learner.
(I'm primarily interested in the US, but I'm curious about other countries also.)

united-states
It is legal to give prospective employees an IQ test, if IQ is a bona fide occupational qualification for the job, and is not merely a ruse for illegal discrimination in a job for which it is not related to a bona fide occupational qualification.
The leading case is Griggs v. Duke Power Co., 401 U.S. 424 (1971). It held that even if there is no discriminatory intent, an employer may not use a job requirement that functionally excludes members of a certain race if it has no relation to measuring performance of job duties. It held that testing or measuring procedures cannot be determinative in employment decisions unless they have some connection to the job.
This ruling, interpreting federal employment discrimination statutes, was superseded by statute, however, by 42 U.S.C. § 2000e–2(h). This amended statute expressly protects the use of “ability tests” not intended to discriminate unlawfully. This was recognized in U.S. v. State of N.C., 914 F. Supp. 1257, 1265–66 (E.D.N.C. 1996), which also observed that "the Supreme Court has overruled Griggs sub silentio". The controlling employment law precedents and statutory language now require employment discrimination to be intentional to give rise to legal liability.
The statute overruling Grigg on this point states in the pertinent part:

Notwithstanding any other provision of this subchapter, it shall not
be an unlawful employment practice . . . for an employer to give and
to act upon the results of any professionally developed ability test
provided that such test, its administration or action upon the results
is not designed, intended or used to discriminate because of race,
color, religion, sex or national origin.

A court case in the U.S. Court of Appeals for the 2nd Circuit in the year 2000 likewise upheld an employer's decision to not hire anyone with an IQ over a certain threshold as a police office (as strange as that may seem).
State law generally tracks the federal law in this regard.

It's even been upheld that an employer (e.g., police in Connecticut) can decline to hire someone because they scored too high on an IQ test. ABC News

@DanielR.Collins Good catch.

Isn't an IQ test supposed to test IQ independent of other factors? Other than having to know the actual language used by the test (lets say "English"), I don't see how a test can be used to discriminate, unless the test itself is incredibly faulty and doesn't actually measure IQ as defined.

@nvoigt I think for the IQ tests actually in use today there is some correlation between average scores and race/ ethnicity of participants. It might not be supposed to be that way but it appears to be that way in practice.

Most IQ tests test are also aptitude tests on specialized areas, such as detecting patterns, 3D Thinking, logical thinking or problem solving. Those are often enough Bona Fida Qualifications, such as seeing errors in patterns for someone doing Quality Control.

@quarague The law expressly allows them in this situation unless you are using them with an intent to discriminate, e.g., in a dish washing job.

An IQ of 100 is roughly an LSAT score of 133, and almost no one who gets below 145 on the LSAT has any realistic chance of passing the bar exam. The patent bar is harder because to be a lawyer admitted to the bar and be a patent lawyer at the same time, you need an engineering BA (there are exceptions but similarly rigorous ones). Basically 0% of people who earn such a degree have an IQ of under 111. Unlike some undergrad majors, engineering has a strong threshold effect.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

france
"No" as asked, but mostly yes
Article L1221-6 du code du travail:

Les informations demandées, sous quelque forme que ce soit, au candidat à un emploi ne peuvent avoir comme finalité que d'apprécier sa capacité à occuper l'emploi proposé ou ses aptitudes professionnelles.
Ces informations doivent présenter un lien direct et nécessaire avec l'emploi proposé ou avec l'évaluation des aptitudes professionnelles.


Information asked in any way to a prospective employee must only have the aim to evaluate their ability to fill the job or their professional abilities.
That information must have a direct and necessary link with the job opening or the evaluation of the candidate’s professional abilities.

You should give your prospective employee a test that is as tailored as possible to the actual requirements of the job. (This is a good idea from a business perspective in addition to the legal angle, by the way.)
That does not mean that you should design from scratch a test tailored to each open position (which would almost surely involve tremendous expense for little benefit); it does not mean that every business decision you make should be sound, either. However, if you purposefully choose a general IQ test over anything that would fit the position better, you are running afoul of the statute. For instance, "intelligent and/or a quick learner" is better measured by a logic test rather than a general IQ test.
The Work Ministry website lists a few types of test, depending on what you want to test in a candidate. Notice that general IQ tests are not on the list.
Hence, my answer to the stated question is "probably not", but it only applies to IQ tests specifically - a whole range of psychotechnical tests are OK.
Other tests are definitely not OK, though. The circulaire DRT 93-10 du 15 mars 1993 says:

(...) si la loi n'institue pas un principe de validité scientifique des méthodes employées, principe qui serait inadapté dans un certain nombre de cas, elle exige un degré raisonnable de fiabilité. Ainsi, le recours à des techniques présentant une marge d'erreur importante ne serait pas conforme à l'obligation de pertinence imposée par la loi.
En cas de litige, il appartiendra au juge d'apprécier la pertinence de la méthode utilisée. (...)


(...) though the statute does not require recruitments methods to be scientifically valid, which would not be easy to interpret in some cases, it still requires a reasonable degree of fiability. Thus, using techniques that involve a large margin of error would not conform to the statute’s relevance requirement.
In case of litigation, the court will appreciate the relevance of the method used. (...)

A circulaire is technically only the government (agency)’s interpretation of statute, and does not have legal force in itself. However, its existence means that an employer using (say) astrology could not argue that scientific validity is irrelevant.

What do you consider to be an IQ test? The original Binet-Simon test? I do not know if they have ever been calibrated against popular American tests but for better or for worse, the “tests de logique” listed on the website you quote are very similar to the WAIS and other similar tests. Ditto for the tests used by the military alluded to on the same website, they include many of the same components (verbal abilities, arithmetic, spatial abilities).

I totally get why you might want to avoid any suggestion that those are “IQ tests” but it's hard to see how they don't suffer from the same flaws or would be a better measure of “intelligence or being a quick learner” as they are very similar in nature and that is exactly what IQ tests are claimed to measure. In practice, that means the conclusion is that using an IQ test is perfectly fine for recruitment purposes in France as long as you use a phrase like “test psychotechnique” or “test de logique” to sidestep the debate on the validity of IQ.

@Relaxed Some "IQ tests" include general knowledge questions (such as: "what is the capital of Greece?", a real question from a real, professional IQ test that I took 25 years ago). Such questions are fairly useless to screen for many positions (e.g., security guard or software engineer), and could easily be viewed as discriminatory based on cultural background. (Replace "what is the capital of Greece" by "what sort of animal is Sun Wukong", and suddenly Chinese / South-East-Asian candidates outperform Westerners.) The content of the test is what matters, not its name.

Yes, indeed, content matters, but the fact is that these “test de logique” are more typical of IQ tests than trivia questions (you can easily check that by perusing the Wikipedia article mentioned in the question). Importantly, in spite of long-standing attempts to make them neutral and claims that they don't depend on culture, those tests have also been shown empirically to be biased and have long been criticized for their lack of relevance to professional performance (there was already a whole literature about that back when I studied occupational psychology 20 years ago).

If I am reading you correctly, evaluating intelligence or learning ability in general (as opposed to abilities specific to the job) is allowed, which basically means that kind of IQ tests the question are referring to are OK, it's only trivia that's not.
